# How to understand Python list comprehension when using 'and' or 'or' in derivation formula?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Using 'and' or 'or' in list comprehension, but the results were unexcepted.why?

```sh
> [print(i) and print(i) for i in range(1)] 
0

> [print(i) or print(i) for i in range(1)]
0
0
```

Comment: What *were* your expected results? What was the point of this code to begin with? You shouldn't use list comprehensions for side effects, for one thing. As to why it prints twice vs once, `print` returns `None`, so `and` only needs to evaluate one operand to know the overall result will be false-y whereas `or` needs to check the second if the first *isn't* truth-y.

Comment: Print returns a NoneType, and that evaluates to False. So if you say None and None that returns None and if you say None or None that evaluates also to False.

Answer (score 0):

The `and` and `or` operators support lazy-evaluation or short-circuiting.

In your first example:

```
[print(i) and print(i) for i in range(1)]
```

First, `print(i)` is executed which writes to stdout. It doesn’t return anything (`None`). Now python knows that this expression is part of an `and` operation. Since `None` has a false boolean, there is no point in evaluating the 2nd `print` as the first one will have needed to return a true boolean value.

With the second one:

```
[print(i) or print(i) for i in range(1)]
```

The same thing begins. Since there’s an `or`, the 2nd `print` is evaluated because there’s a chance of it being successful. That’s why two 0s are written to stdout.

The actual results of both are lost as the list comprehension isn’t assigned to anything. The results would be `[None]` for both. The 2 logic operators do check the boolean values, but also return the objects involved.

With `x and y`, the object `y` always returned. 
With `x or y`,

- if `x` is a ‘truthy’ object, `x` is returned
- otherwise `y` is returned

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with list-comprehension:

```
>>> print(0) and print(0)
0
>>> print(0) or print(0)
0
0
```

This is the [normal behavior of boolean operators in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression x and y first **evaluates x**; if x is false, its value is returned
>
> The expression x or y first **evaluates x**; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, **y is evaluated** and the resulting value is returned.

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If you know that `print(0)` returns `None`:

```
>>> print(0) is None
0
True
```

And that:

> the following values are interpreted as false: False, **None**, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers

You have your answer:

- `and` case: evaluate `print(0)` (prints `0` as side effect), that is false and return its value (`None`)
- `or` case: evaluate `print(0)` (prints `0`), that is false and then evaluate the second `print(0)` (prints `0`) return its value (`None`).